# How do i remove ubuntu 16.04 without disrupting ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, upgrade, 32-bit

I am using a 64bit octo-core 2.4ghz server. that has ubuntu 14.04 32bit installed. along with ubuntu 16.04 32 bit installed.
i would like to remove ubuntu 16.04 without touching ubuntu 14.04 it has all my important files on it.
and i would then like to, once 16.04 is removed, i would like to install ubuntu 20.04 64 bit.
does anyone know how to remove ubuntu 16.04 and not damage anyother files out of it's partition ?
thanks in advance.
Matthew

---

well tbh they are my moms files.
currently i have ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 running on dual boot.
all i want to do is remove ubuntu 16.04 without damaging 14.04...
i think i would have to go into the partition editor and delete the partition for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: "it has all my important files on it"   That means you have backups and know how to restore one so that should not be an issue ;-) Please add a disk lay-out to the question otherwise we would be guessing on what needs to be done.

Comment: You don't need to remove 16.04, you just install 20.04 into the partition(s) where 16.04 / *xenial* currently resides.   It's a QA-tested install (replace partition; for *flavors* anyway)   Backup your files first obviously.   Note: 32-bit 20.04 does **not** exist, and it's not entirely clear if you're talking desktop or server (you do mention server).

Comment: FYI: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic on this site, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: thanks karel that is exactly what i needed